# I'm suddenly getting the error :EntityMetadataWrapperException

Tags: entities

I'm running a Drupal 7.21 site that uses the Entity Reference module (v.7.x-1.0) to support reusing image nodes in other node types. After several months of smooth sailing , I'm seeing a new error when I try to view image nodes on my site. The error is:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   field_entity_image. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()

The property named in the error, "field_entity_image", is the name of an Entity Reference field that exists on other node types (article, basic page). However, those other content types don't throw the error when I try to view them. What is new is the fact that I created a new node type (bio) that also uses the existing field_entity_image field.

I've seen this error discussed in relation to certain modules (Commerce being one) but not as the result of creating new content type or adding entity reference fields. If anyone has insights into this, all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to update this post, we've now upgraded to Drupal 7.22, and the issue is still with us. I've also noticed that the error isn't confined to nodes whose fields include an image field or entity reference field. It appears to affect all content nodes other than Basic Page and Article, i.e. all the custom types we've created. Does anyone have any updated info about this error and what might be causing it? Again, many thanks.

Comment: (I work with Laurance).  In fact, the issue appears to affect all content types that do not use the "field_entity_image" field.  Adding this field to the content type makes the error message go away.  Deleting it again makes the error come back.  This doesn't seem right, but it does seem to be the case.

Comment: I've also confirmed that the issue occurs with minimal contributed modules-- I was able to pare down to basically just field modules and their dependencies (Date, Date API, Computed Field, Entity Reference, Entitity API, and CTools) and the problem still exists.

Comment: Update your "Entity" and "Entity Refference" modules, it must resolve this issue

Comment: Hello. Are you suer about that? Could you point us to issue in queue that is resolved (fixed) and dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your site has not been running on Drupal 7.21 for several months. You have recently upgraded.

There was a security fix in the drupal core image module in 7.20 which broke several contributed modules. 7.21 has a new variable to mitigate the problem, but if your issue involves images, it is probably related to the security fix. For more information read the [release notes](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.21-release-notes).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the same issue we're experiencing, unfortunately.  See comments above for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar weirdness with the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) data wrappers.  The root cause of the problem in my case, and in the [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module, was the stable version of [UUID](http://drupal.org/project/uuid).  Upgrading the the dev version solved all of my issues.  Searching for UUID in both of the issue queues will give you more insight.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be module related-- we've confirmed that the issue persists with minimal contributed modules (see comments on original question).